# Receiving error 'the connection has failed error' while trying to connect to Oracle Datasource from Oracle BI Admin tool

Tags: linux, repository, connection-string, business-intelligence, obiee

I have installed Oracle BIEE, Oracle Database on Linux and I have installed BI Admin tool on my machine. Now i want to add the database on linux as a source and create a repository. But when i am trying to add DB on linux as source, i am receining the error 'The connection has failed error'. What else need to be done to connect to the db?

Comment: What does the admin tool log say? The log will be located in the same directory as your admin tool.

Comment: Check the admin tool log, as @jackohug said. Also try using EasyConnect syntax instead of TNSnames to avoid any issues with tnsnames.ora location (if it then works, you can work backwards and fix your problem from there)